# Speeding up boot time

Tags: boot, steam, tweak

I'm setting up a PC in the living room for Steam Big Picture (a "media center" version of Steam, which can also stream videogames from another computer on the local network).

All the computer has to do is to boot up, log in into the default user and launch Steam.

Being a media center, I need it to boot fast.

With the default configuration it took 1:46 m from the press of the power button to Steam.

I've tried to optimize some things.

Here's what I've already done:

- Installed the `preload` package
- Installed the `readahead-fedora` package
- Changed `CONCURRENCY=makefile` into `CONCURRENCY=shell` in `/etc/init.d/rc` (read the EDIT below)
- Reduced `GRUB_TIMEOUT` to `0`
- Disabled some unnecessary services with the `rcconf` command

With these tweaks I've achieved about 20-25 seconds of speed up, but it's still not so good.

How can I figure out what does it exactly do in the ~65 seconds between the POST and Gnome3?

EDIT: Apparently the `/etc/init.d/rc` script changes `shell` back into `makefile`, they are the same thing but the first one is deprecated.

Comment: Not a "proper" solution but have you considered suspending instead of shutting down the system?

Comment: Or hibernate instead of shutdown.

Comment: Suspending would be a good solution, because I would also be able to wake the computer up with a wireless keyboard, but I want to optimize the system the most possible. If something useless is launched during the boot it will most likely impact the performance on the PC even after the boot.

Comment: have you considered this: http://www.webupd8.org/2013/12/install-steamos-session-in-ubuntu.html that would take out loading of gnome3

Comment: @Mateo: sadly, I can't. I'm using a laptop connected to a TV, and the SteamOS compositor doesn't support more than one monitor even if only one is actually active.